# adding new hosts in icinga web

Tags: icinga, ubuntu-12.10

Using Ubuntu 12.10 server. 
icinga with idoutils and icinga-web.
Have ability to see hosts if I add them in the localhost_icinga.cfg

however from my understanding you can create a host.cfg based on systems.
example: windows.cfg to monitor all windows machines via NSclient++ (similar to Nagios)

Everytime I create a new host.cfg icinga either gives me a duplicate error or it does not like the define host line.
 Example:
    (localhost_icinga.cfg *working*)

define host{
     use generic-host
     host_name  mikedoppdesk
     alias  mikedoppdesk
     address 192.168.0.56
}
 However if I create a windows.cfg 
 Example:
   define host{
      use windows
      host_name mikedoppdesk
      alias mikedoppdesk
      address 192.168.0.56
}

and use: /usr/sbin/icinga -v /etc/icinga/icinga.cfg

output error line 1 windows.cfg

I have been chasing the icinga web docs trying to get a straight answer. I know I am missing something critical but cannot find rhyme or reason.
Please educate or prove me dumb.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In your main configuration file which is usually /usr/local/icinga/etc/icinga.cfg you should add a line with no spaces at the beginning:

```
cfg_file=/usr/local/icinga/etc/conf.d/hosts.cfg
```

(you can see it here as well: http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/configobject.html).

It means that you define objects (here hosts) in the file specified above. In that file you should define the monitored host itself

Example:

```
 define host{
        host_name                       bogus-router
        alias                           Bogus Router #1
        address                         192.168.1.254
        parents                         server-backbone
        check_command                   check-host-alive
        check_interval                  5
        retry_interval                  1
        max_check_attempts              5
        check_period                    24x7
        process_perf_data               0
        retain_nonstatus_information    0
        contact_groups                  router-admins
        notification_interval           30
        notification_period             24x7
        notification_options            d,u,r
        }
```

All possible options and their definitions you can be found here (http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/objectdefinitions.html#objectdefinitions-host).

Comment: getting this error while adding hosts in icinga : information/cli: Requesting a signed certificate from the master.
critical/cli: Could not fetch valid response. Please check the master log (notice or debug).
critical/cli: Failed to request certificate from Icinga 2 master.